# How to Get Rid of Ripples from a Gradient Image of a Smoothed Image?

Tags: image-processing, filters, noise, lowpass-filter, opencv

I have a gray scale `UINT8` image. When I smooth it with a Gaussian filter and then compute the gradient image with a Sobel filter in *OpenCV*, ripples would appear.

The first image is what happens when I use a 25x25 Gaussian filter with sigma value 4 and compute the second order derivative in the x direction with a size 3 Sobel filter.

[image]

The more I smooth the image, the more significant the ripples become.

The second image is what I got when I use a 49x49 Gaussian filter with sigma value 7. The Sobel filter is the same as the first image.

[image]

Why is the Gaussian filter creating more noise when it's suppose to get rid of them? How should I deal with this?

Comment: Could you tell us about the Image (Is it UINT8 / UINT16, Floating Point, which Gaussian Filter do you use, etc...)?

Comment: I've edited my question to include more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it happens due to 2 things:

1. Quantization
   You are working using `UINT8` Image, try convert it into floating Point Image.
   You may do this by `mO = im2double(mI)` where `mI` is the `UINT8` and `mO` is a floating point image in the range `[0, 1]`. You may also do it using `mO = double(mI) / 255`.
2. Gaussian Kernel Radius vs STD Ratio
   Your Gaussian Filter Radius is 12 while $ \sigma = 4 $. This is a ratio of 3. Try higher ratios, something like `kernelRadius = ceil(5 * kernelStd)` this will make the Gaussian Filter result much smoother.

Comment: You're right, I converted it to floating point and smoothed it. The ripples are gone! Thank you so much!

Comment: You're most welcome. Enjoy...